# How to dismiss keyboard when pressing Search key on tableView in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, xcode8.2

How to dismiss keyboard when pressing Search key? I have a search bar on tableView and I used the following method. It did't work. Any Idea why? Thanks in advance.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true

}
```

UPDATE 2.0 ----------------------------------------------------

This picture is what I am trying to do, when I click search key nothing happened.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6uK9.png)

I have my UISearchBar delegate has set already

```
class SearchVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate  {


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

var data = [// my data here.]

var filteredData: [String]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self
    searchBar.delegate = self
    filteredData = data


    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
    tableView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

}
```

Comment: You can use https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager, if convenient.

Comment: can you check have you set the textField delegate ?

Comment: `textFiledShouldReturn` should be `textFieldShouldReturn`... "Field" in methodname

Comment: are you useing UISearchbar'

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Yes, I am using UISearchbar on tableView. I am trying to make keyboard dismiss when pressing Search key.

Comment: @sweta.me , I just updated my code still not working.

Comment: @QQ10 - check my answer

Comment: @Ram I don't think so? Do I need textField delegate even on UISearchbar?

Comment: no if you are using UISearchBar then no need to set textfield delegate  . You make sure UISearchBar delegate has set @QQ10

Comment: @Ram I don't have func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) { } function. What should I do inside this function?

Comment: @Ram Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are using UISearchBar then first make sure its delegate is set 
and then add this function

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)  {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: HI, I already have this function. What I am trying to do is when I tap Search bar keyboard shows up and when I click search key, the key board dismiss. I am not sure how to do the second part.

Comment: can you check you have set UIsearchBar delegate

Comment: I don't have func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) { } function. What should I do inside this function?

Comment: class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        /* Setup delegates */
        searchBar.delegate = self
    }
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I fixed my issue. I missed func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) { searchBar.resignFirstResponder() }

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me.

'searchActive' is used to switch between the filtered values and the original unfiltered values.

'initialUseOfSearchBar' is used to show the keyboard the first time around but after that keyboard is hidden when user presses clear 'x'.

```
var initialUseOfSearchBar = true

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = true

    if searchBar.text?.characters.count == 0 {
        searchActive = false

        if initialUseOfSearchBar == false {
            searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    if searchText.characters.count == 0 {
        searchActive = false;
        tableView.reloadData()
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    initialUseOfSearchBar = false

   ...

}
```

...

Answer (score 0):

make sure in `viewDidLoad()` you do `self.textField.delegate = self` and of course your `viewController` must conform to the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol.  Then, make sure you are spelling the function correctly `textFieldShouldReturn()`